# amazon prime keeps buffering

Tags: amazon, streaming, amazon-prime

I have 25 Mbps home wifi modem connection, I am currently streaming on a smart tv through a ps3 app, Netflix and Hulu work fine, my ps3 is completely upgraded I have reset my internet connection an restarted my ps3, but amazon prime still won't stream on my tv without buffering every 2 minutes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about using a cloud service on a TV not about using a web application.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem. The only cure seems to be to to exit the browser completely, then open it back up and go to the video again. It should pick up where you left off.

I don't think it's a problem with your internet, but more likely the enormous number of users watching videos on Amazon is overwhelming their server.